# Going to Sweden before going to the UAE from Tunisia

Tags: schengen

I got a UAE work visa and I'm going to Dubai for the first time. But before that I want to travel to Sweden for a 1-week training. So I'll need a Schengen visa too.

Is there any problem applying for a Schengen visa from Tunisia and book a one-way ticket from Tunisia to Sweden, then a one-way ticket from Sweden to Dubai? Or is it mandatory to go back to Tunisia before travelling to Dubai?

Answer (score 2):

Neither Sweden nor the UAE will have any problems with that itinerary.

(Of course, it *may* be a challenge to convince the Swedish consulate that you're going to leave after your visit, if your ties to Tunisia are weak enough that you're willing to go to the UAE for work, and you're not established in the UAE with any strong ties *yet*. But that's independent of whether your physical travel goes directly from Sweden to UAE or via Tunisia, so don't let that determine your routing).

Comment: Thanks Henning for your comment. The point is that I still don't have an UAE immigrant status otherwise i'll be forced to apply for the schengen visa from Dubai. I was in VFS global center this morning and they suggested me to come back to Tunisia before travelling to Dubai because with the current routing the visa application can be rejected.

Comment: @Mehdi: VFS is a glorified courier service. They have nothing whatsoever to do with _deciding_ visa applications, and we have plenty of reports of their employees plainly having no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: VFS contacted the swedish embassy and they said that I can apply but thete is big chance that the application will berejected.

Comment: @Mehdi as Henning said, there could be plenty of reasons that have nothing to do with the routing, but a lot to do with your reasons for leaving Tunisia and the lack of reasons to actually get to the UAE. Anyway, as the cost of a ticket is going to be substantially higher if you go through Sweden, what is your actual reason to go there “on your way” to Dubai?

Comment: @jcaron : I'm going to stockholm for one week training and then i'll travel to dubai to start working there. I already have a mission order from my employer which indicate the reason of my trip to sweden.

Comment: Are you going to the UAE on a limited-time mission for your existing employer? Do you have a long term contract in Tunisia for when you end your mission in the UAE? Or is it your ne UAE employer sending your for training to Sweden? Did you provide all this information and supporting documentation?

Comment: I'm joining a new company based in UAE. I already got the UAE  work visa but I will travel for the first time to start working in Dubai. My UAE employer is sending me before to sweden for training then from there I will go to Dubai. I will apply for the schengen visa from Tunisia . The question : is it mandatory to return to the Contry (Tunisia) ? Or i can directly go to dubai from sweden ?